# How to delete all mail in solaris

Tags: solaris, email

I have bunch of mails in my solaris account

```
107 letters found in /var/mail/icinga, 1 scheduled for deletion, 0 newly arrived
  107  d  2886   MAILER-DAEMON  Fri Jun 11 00:39:39 2010
> 106     2895   MAILER-DAEMON  Fri Jun 11 00:13:02 2010
  105     2890   MAILER-DAEMON  Fri Jun 11 00:10:05 2010
  104     2888   MAILER-DAEMON  Tue May 18 15:13:34 2010
  103     2874   MAILER-DAEMON  Tue May 18 14:58:29 2010
  102     2874   MAILER-DAEMON  Tue May 18 14:28:34 2010
```

Any idea how can i delete all of them with 1 command line instead of line by line?

Comment: Which mail program?  All Solaris releases include `mail` (not so user friendly) and `mailx` (slightly more user friendly).  Many sites / newer releases also install much more user friendly & powerful command line mail readers such as `mutt`, `elm`, and `pine` (plus of course Thunderbird and Evolution at sites running it as a desktop).

Answer (score 5):

```
rm /var/mail/${user}
```

Answer (score 3):

mailx has many more features, including batch deleting messages.

use d for the delete subcommand and h to show the headers of messages in the mailbox.

```
mailx
mailx version 5.0  Type ? for help.


"/var/mail//myuser": 11 messages: 11 new

>N  1 My User        Wed Mar 28 17:50   27/1073  Output from "cron" comman
 N  2 My User        Wed Mar 28 18:56 3226/253350 Output from "cron" comman
 N  3 My User        Wed Mar 28 21:17   24/896   Output from "cron" comman
 N  4 My User        Thu Mar 29 21:17   24/896   Output from "cron" comman
 N  5 My User        Fri Mar 30 17:50   27/1073  Output from "cron" comman
 N  6 My User        Fri Mar 30 18:56 3226/253347 Output from "cron" comman
 N  7 My User        Fri Mar 30 21:17   24/896   Output from "cron" comman
 N  8 My User        Sun Apr  1 21:18   24/896   Output from "cron" comman
 N  9 My User        Mon Apr  2 17:50   27/1070  Output from "cron" comman
 N 10 My User        Mon Apr  2 18:56 3226/253344 Output from "cron" comman
 N 11 My User        Mon Apr  2 21:17   24/893   Output from "cron" comman
> ? d 1-11
> ? h
No applicable messages
? q
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if solaris mail is the same as under Linux and can't test right now, but in Linux you would issue the command `d 102-107` at the mail prompt (and get a help page if you enter `?`).

Comment: it returns 'Illegal numeric'

Comment: Maybe because 107 is already marked as deleted? Try `d 102-106` and see `man mail`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works on Solaris (it does under FreeBSD which is mailx afaik), but try `d *` inside the mail client.

Answer (score 1):

Will two commands do?

```
!>/var/mail/icinga
q
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero out the file with /dev/null.

`# cat /dev/null > /var/mail/{user}`

Comment: `> /var/mail/{user}` is enough to create a 0 bytes file.